# Clojure partition list of strings, accumulating the result

Tags: clojure

I'm sorry about the lack of precision in the title, but it might illustrate my lack of clojure experience.

I'm trying to take a large list of strings, and convert that list into another list of strings, concatenating as I go until the accumulator is less than some length.

For example, if I have

```
[ "a" "bc" "def" "ghij" ]
```

and my max string length is 4, I would walk down the list, accumulating the concat, until my accumulation len > 4, and then start the accumulator from scratch. My result would look like:

```
[ "abc" "def" "ghij" ]
```

I can't seem to come up with the proper incantation for `partition-by`, and it's driving me a little crazy. I've been trying to make my accumulator an `atom` (but can't seem to figure out where to `reset!`), but other than that, I can't see where/how to keep track of my accumulated string.

Thanks in advance to anyone taking mercy on me.

Comment: Thanks to all responders - I'm sitll using all suggestions as a learning experience, and will accept an answer when/if I ever understand. Thanks again!

Comment: There was some uncertainty as to your exact requirements. Could you please look at the unit tests included in my answer and verify that is the behavior you were seeking?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defn catsize [limit strs]
  (reduce (fn [res s]
              (let [base (peek res)]
                (if (> (+ (.length ^String base) (.length ^String s)) limit)
                  (conj res s)
                  (conj (pop res) (str base s)))))
          (if (seq strs) [(first strs)] [])
          (rest strs)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on this:

```clj
(defn collapse [maxlen xs]
  (let [concats (take-while #(< (count %) maxlen) (reductions str xs))]
    (cons (last concats) (drop (count concats) xs))))
(collapse 4 ["a" "bc" "def" "ghij"])
;; => ("abc" "def" "ghij")
```

Comment: the approach is correct, but it works just in case the subsequence is in the beginning of the input. Would fail for `(collapse 4 ["a" "bc" "def" "ghij" "z" "xc" "vbn"])` => `("abc" "def" "ghij" "z" "xc" "vbn")` , or `(collapse 4 ["asdf" "a" "bc" "def" "ghij"])` => `(nil "asdf" "a" "bc" "def" "ghij")` .. That should be fixed somehow )))

Answer (score 1):

This gets pretty close. I'm not sure why you have j at the end of the final string.

```
(sequence
 (comp
  (mapcat seq)
  (partition-all 3)
  (map clojure.string/join))
 ["a" "bc" "def" "ghij"]) => ("abc" "def" "ghi" "j")
```

Answer (score -4):

Here is how I would do it:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(def bound 4)

(defn catter [strings-in]
  (loop [merged-strs    []
         curr-merge     (first strings-in)
         remaining-strs (rest strings-in)]
   ;(newline) (spyx [merged-strs curr-merge remaining-strs])
    (if (empty? remaining-strs)
      (conj merged-strs curr-merge)
      (let          ; try using 'let-spy' instead
        [new-str   (first remaining-strs)
         new-merge (str curr-merge new-str)]
        (if (< (count new-merge) bound)
          (recur merged-strs new-merge (rest remaining-strs))
          (recur (conj merged-strs curr-merge) new-str (rest remaining-strs)))))))

(dotest
  (is=  ["abc" "def" "ghij"]     (catter ["a" "bc" "def" "ghij"]) )
  (is=  ["abc" "def" "ghij"]     (catter ["a" "b" "c" "def" "ghij"]) )
  (is=  ["abc" "def" "ghij"]     (catter ["a" "b" "c" "d" "ef" "ghij"]) )
  (is=  ["abc" "def" "ghij"]     (catter ["a" "bc" "d" "ef" "ghij"]) )
  (is=  ["abc" "def" "ghij"]     (catter ["a" "bc" "d" "e" "f" "ghij"]) )

  (is=  ["abc" "def" "gh" "ij"]  (catter ["abc" "d" "e" "f" "gh" "ij"]) )
  (is=  ["abc" "def" "ghi" "j"]  (catter ["abc" "d" "e" "f" "ghi" "j"]) )

  (is=  ["abcdef" "ghi" "j"]     (catter ["abcdef" "ghi" "j"]) )
  (is=  ["abcdef" "ghi" "j"]     (catter ["abcdef" "g" "h" "i" "j"]) )
)
```

You will need to add `[tupelo "0.9.71"]` to project dependencies.

---

## Update:

If you user `spy` and `let-spy`, you can see the process the algorithm uses to arrive at the result.  For example:

```
(catter ["a" "b" "c" "d" "ef" "ghij"]) )   =>     ["abc" "def" "ghij"]     

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
strings-in => ["a" "b" "c" "d" "ef" "ghij"]

[merged-strs curr-merge remaining-strs] => [[] "a" ("b" "c" "d" "ef" "ghij")]
new-str => "b"
new-merge => "ab"

[merged-strs curr-merge remaining-strs] => [[] "ab" ("c" "d" "ef" "ghij")]
new-str => "c"
new-merge => "abc"

[merged-strs curr-merge remaining-strs] => [[] "abc" ("d" "ef" "ghij")]
new-str => "d"
new-merge => "abcd"

[merged-strs curr-merge remaining-strs] => [["abc"] "d" ("ef" "ghij")]
new-str => "ef"
new-merge => "def"

[merged-strs curr-merge remaining-strs] => [["abc"] "def" ("ghij")]
new-str => "ghij"
new-merge => "defghij"

[merged-strs curr-merge remaining-strs] => [["abc" "def"] "ghij" ()]

Ran 2 tests containing 10 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```